# Ansible block vars

Tags: variables, ansible

How can I set in Ansible block vars (visible only for tasks in block) ?

I tried:

```
---
- hosts: test
  tasks:
    - block:

       - name: task 1
         shell: "echo {{item}}"

      with_items:
        - one
        - two
```

but it seems that it's a wrong way.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

- If you want to define a variable for a block:

  ```
  - block:

    - debug:
        var: var_for_block

    vars:
      var_for_block: "value for var_for_block"
  ```
- If you want to "loop over blocks" as your code suggests - you can't. It's not implemented in Ansible.
  Follow [this thread](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/13262).

  For now consider saving the tasks to a separate file and use `include` instead.

Comment: so in paragraph "Variable Precedence: Where Should I Put A Variable?" oat http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html  - there is item "block vars (only for tasks in block)", and the question is "What is it?"

Comment: ok, i try to block vars - somehow - but i don't really know how to declare them ?

Comment: you right, thx, i've tried before but i put var at the beginning of the block and that syntax doesn't work.

Comment: @itiic In case you want to loop over block, you may try this alternate: https://shasawas.wordpress.com/2016/05/23/how-to-loop-over-a-set-of-tasks-in-ansible/

Comment: Yes @Shasha99 include with with_items is useful but blocks provide try/catch syntax and variable precedence is different.

Answer (score 1):

@Shasha99 
you might be able to include a file with  a block in it so you can still benefit from the try/catch

includeFile.yml :

```
- block
    - name: Finding the package.
      shell: rpm -qa | grep "{{pkgName}}"
      register: package

    - name: Uninstalling the package.
      shell: rpm -e "{{package}}"
  always:
    - debug: msg="this always executes"
```

main.yml:

```
---
- hosts: all
  vars: 
    - packageList : ["pkg1","pkg2","pkg3","pkg4"]

  tasks:
    - include: includeFile.yml pkgName="{{item}}"
      with_items: packageList
```